# What is the difference between pipeline and lane in terms of CPU architecture?

Tags: gpu, cpu-architecture, simd

I am recently reading the book *"computer architecture: a quantitative approach"* by *Jonh  L. Hennessy & David A. Patterson*.
I find that the term *"Lane"* is extensively used in Chapter 4 but not explicitly and formally defined.

The first places it appears is as follows:
*"All modern vector computers have vector functional units with multiple parallel pipelines (or lanes) that can produce two or more results per clock cycle ..."* in Page 290 (6th version).

I am a little confused about the terms "Lane" and "pipeline". Are they the same thing?

Comment: The two terms are synonyms in that chapter. A lane is the name of the unit that is used to describe the width of an execution unit. For example, an execution unit with two 32-bit lanes can execute a vector instruction with two 32-bit elements. This is in contrast to splitting the vector instruction into two micro-instructions, each is executed by an execution unit. The same execution unit might be able to also operate as one with four 16-bit lanes. The term "pipeline" is also often used to refer to the whole pipeline of the processor...

Comment: ...So the meaning of the term depends on the context. A lane is not necessarily fully pipelined (i.e., can complete one scalar operation per cycle). Also a lane is not necessarily implemented as an actual physical path in the execution unit, but this is the usual way of implementing vector execution units.

Comment: The term lane is also used in the PCIe standard to refer to a pair of wires, one is used for sending a single bit and the other is used for receiving a single bit. A PCIe slot that is x16 wide has 16 lanes and can accommodate a PCIe card that is 16-wide or smaller.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is still unclear for me what does the number of pipelines means? For example, for a CPU having 5-staged pipelines, we say the CPU has a pipeline or has 5 pipelines?

Answer (score 1):

A "lane" in this context is a SIMD element.  (They're talking about vector execution units, *not* superscalar CPUs that run more than one instruction in parallel throughout "the pipeline" of the whole CPU.  In practice you have both)

e.g. x86 SSE `addps xmm0, xmm1` does 4x float32 additions with one instruction, treating the XMM registers as 4 lanes of 32-bit float.

It runs on a SIMD execution unit that has 4 single-precision FP adders in parallel.  This execution unit is pipelined, typically 3 or 4 cycle latency and 1/clock throughput.

In this case your textbook is talking about the pipeline(s) inside one execution unit.  As far as pipelining is concerned, it makes little different what the operation is, and whether it's 4x 32-bit or 2x 64-bit or whatever.  At the buffers between pipeline stages, there's a certain number of bits to latch, and the latches don't really care how it's interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you understand what **pipelining** is.

> **Pipelining** is an implementation technique where multiple instructions are overlapped in execution. The computer pipeline is divided in stages. Each stage completes a part of an instruction in parallel. The stages are connected one to the next to form a pipe - instructions enter at one end, progress through the stages, and exit at the other end.

In your scenario, having multiple lanes on a road will increase the car **throughput**. You will have more cars reaching the end destination. However, your car speed will be the same. It is the same with pipelining.

> Pipelining does not decrease the time for individual instruction execution. Instead, it increases instruction **throughput**. The throughput of the instruction pipeline is determined by how often an instruction exits the pipeline.

Check [this website](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~prabhu/Tutorial/PIPELINE/pipe_title.html) for more information.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems to me that one pipeline is a lane in my context. However, I still do not clear how to count the number of the pipelines? For the figure labeled as "Lane 2", is it suitable to say that the figure gives two pipelines? Or, in contrast, the single pipeline consists of two lanes?